# TradingView (Pine Script) backtest "no data" on Futures (Commodities) data? such as silver, gold...?

Tags: pine-script

I cannot do backtesting on Comodities data on Trading View. I don't know if its common or is it just me?

The backtesting code works fine on stock, crypto, Forex but not FUTURES such as NO1! Simply display no data on backtest. But if I draw plots, it still shows.

Any one knows why? Is it simply not supported?

```
//@version=4
strategy("SMA", overlay=true, default_qty_type = strategy.percent_of_equity, 
             default_qty_value=99, initial_capital=10000, currency=currency.USD)
strategy.risk.allow_entry_in(strategy.direction.long)

fast = input(defval=15, title="fast", type = input.integer)
slow = input(defval=28, title="slow", type = input.integer)

SMA_fast = sma(close, fast)
SMA_slow = sma(close, slow)

start = timestamp(2020, 1, 30, 0, 0)

p1 = plot(SMA_fast, title="fast", color= SMA_fast>=SMA_slow ? color.orange: SMA_fast<=SMA_slow ? color.black: color.black, linewidth=2)
p2 = plot(SMA_slow, title="slow", color=color.blue, linewidth=2)
fill(p1, p2, color = SMA_fast>=SMA_slow ? color.orange : color.blue, transp = 30)


longCondition = crossover(SMA_fast, SMA_slow)
if (longCondition) and time > start
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
    alert("BUY (" + tostring(close) + ")", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    
shortCondition = crossunder(SMA_fast, SMA_slow)
if (shortCondition) and time > start
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
    alert("SELL (" + tostring(close) + ")", alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silver & Gold are both over $10,000 per contract and you have your initial_capital set to 10,000. Either try a futures contract that is below $10,000 per contract like the S&P500 ES1!, or increase your initial capital.

Because of leverage I usually use contracts for futures, rather than % of equity.

You don't need to rewrite your code, Whenever you want to test your strategy on futures just click the setting gear icon for your strategy then click Properties. You can change your initial capital and Order Size settings to Contracts right in the settings screen.